# dotnet publish command is not creating zip file package for asp.net core web application project

Tags: msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, dotnet-cli

I am trying to create a web deployment package for asp.net core web application. When I tried to publish the output as a package using VS2017, I got all the necessary files in "Publish" folder as well a zip file containing all those files in given location.

However I want to have the same using command line. I am able to get  "Publish" folder, but not a zip file. What am I doing wrong? Can someone correct my command?

```
dotnet publish /p:target=package /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:LastUsedBuildConfiguration=Release /p:LastUsedPlatform="Any CPU" /p:LaunchSiteAfterPublish=True /p:ExcludeApp_Data=False /p:PublishFramework=netcoreapp1.0 /p:UsePowerShell=True /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation=C:\Kannan\Temp\package.zip /p:PackageLocation="C:\kannan\temp\package.zip" /p:PackageFileName=C:\kannan\temp\package.zip /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true
```

Comment: @Leo-MSFT: This url solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong? Can someone correct my command?

It`s depends on the version of your cli.

If you are using the 2.0 version of cli, then you can use dotnet publish command on a windows machine and it would work.

```
dotnet build WebApplicationDeploy.sln /nologo /p:PublishProfile=Release /p:PackageLocation="C:\Some\Path\package" /p:OutDir="C:\Some\Path\out" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /maxcpucount:1 /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release" /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="C:\Some\Path\package\package.zip"
```

But if **you are using 1.0.4 version of the cli, then you should use the msbuild version of the command** (The ability to call dotnet build was added in 2.0 cli).

```
msbuild WebApplicationDeploy.sln /nologo /p:PublishProfile=Release /p:PackageLocation="C:\Some\Path\package" /p:OutDir="C:\Some\Path\out" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /maxcpucount:1 /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release" /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="C:\Some\Path\package\package.zip"
```

For the detail info, you can refer to [the same issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6598) on GitHub.

Comment: What is the correct syntax for above e.g. /p:something=abc on Linux and OSX (dotnet 2 and 3 concerned)?

Comment: Ooh I could hug you! (in a safe, socially distanced kind of way, obviously)

Answer (score 2):

I used `dotnet publish -c Release /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageLocation="C:\Temp"` for Uno Platform app and it works well

Maybe it is because you put full file name to `/p:PackageLocation=` instead of the folder?

Comment: FYI, this works if you on windows, it doesn't work on a linux agent as it wouldn't have webdeploy binaries | The specified task executable location "IIS/Microsoft Web Deploy V3/msdeploy.exe" is invalid