# Dot Net Cli not generating zip file for webproject (dot net core 2)

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-2.0, dotnet-cli

Just started with .net core 2 linux and i am trying to build and generate a deployable zip file for azure web app.

I am running this command after build

```
dotnet publish MyProjectSolution.sln /nologo /p:PackageLocation="C:\Some\Path\AESWebPortal" /p:OutDir="C:\Some\Path\out" /p:DeployOnBuild=false /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /maxcpucount:1 /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release" /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="C:\Some\Path\package\package.zip"
```

this is the error that i get when running this

```
 \bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\publish\
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\PublishTargets
\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeployPackage.targets(96,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" is invalid. 
[C:\Jenkins\workspace\test\AESWebPortal\AESWebPortal.csproj]
```

The idea is that i want to migrate to linux as a build machine but i still need the zip for classic deployment

Some help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running this command on a Linux machine?

Comment: currently tried on windows, will try on linux later as well

Comment: with publish, managed without parameters to generate the files, but not a zip to contain the files

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45678801/1143474) or [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6598)? They both, eventually, offer the same advice.

Comment: yep, same problem

Comment: Looking at the stack trace, does the following file exist on your system: `C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe`?