# What Changes to my VSTS build need to be made for .net core Web Api Deploy to Azure

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm attempting to use VSTS to build and deploy my .net core Web API Web App Service.

It appears that previous versions of .net (including somewhat recent versions of .net core) created a zip file. The default configuration for an Azure App Service Deploy have the field **Package or Folder** set to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip` by default. This was failing for me with the error `No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\s\**\*.zip`

I was able to get it to kind of succeed by changing the path to simply `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`, but from the Azure console I can see that this deploys everything (not just the binaries)

I could add a trainload of questions following this, but I'll keep this specific.

P.s.> I already looked here: [dotnet publish command is not creating zip file package for asp.net core web application project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650369/dotnet-publish-command-is-not-creating-zip-file-package-for-asp-net-core-web-app), but it appears to be a different problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check **Zip Published Projects** option of **.NET Core Publish** task and specify output argument (`--output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory`)

[image]

Then the Web API project will be published and zipped to a package in the **artifact directory**, after that you can specify `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/**/*.zip` in Package or Folder input box if you deploy the app during the same build.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. It would be great if this were the default output in VSO

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully understand the questions, but I can give your some suggestion points.

**1. Clean Sources**

On "Get Sources" step choose Clean -> true -> Sources and Output.
This will ensure cleaning all old code.

**2. Create package**

After build use "dotnet publish" step. In "Path to project(s)" as POC I recommend to set path to your project:

{Your Solution}/{Your Project}/{Your Project}.csproj

You don't need to add "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)" it is automatically added to path your enter. This will create package.zip file.

**3. Copy package**

Use "Copy Files" step. For "Target Folder" choose  $(build.artifactstagingdirectory). As pattern set "**/*.zip". This will ensure, that only package files will be used for deploy.

**4. Deploy package**

Use "Azure App Service Deploy". As "Package or Folder" choose one of

$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/**/*.zip

$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/{Your Solution}/{Your Project}/**/*.zip

Hope it helps.