# Azure Pipelines: task PublishBuildArtifacts avoid zip

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So I'm running this command

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: 'src/myproj/*.csproj'
    arguments: -o $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)
```

And it is generating as Published Artifacts in a drop folder (Yes!), but as a zip file (myproj.zip).

I want to avoid the zip and would rather want the output as a full folder.

I'm researching but I cant find where this is being done.

The funny thing is that I tried it on my own CMD window and it is outputing the folder, but in Azure Pipelines it is generating a zip file.

Comment: and even funnier, though I know they are not exactly the same, the vsbuild for netfw allows me to generate folder (not zip) and dotnet publish should be pretty much the same (since it uses msbuild in the background)

Comment: Could you look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45678801/7073340)

Comment: What is your `dotnet build` task?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please try the `zipAfterPublish` property (see also [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=vsts)), optional in combination with the `modifyOutputPath` property.

This would result in the following yaml snippet:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: 'src/myproj/*.csproj'
    arguments: -o $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false
```

Comment: lifesaver! +1000!, works perfect!, wow, I completely missed it from the docs