# Azure Pipelines: task PublishBuildArtifacts avoid zip [Asp.Net]

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**.Net Core - Publish Artifact Task**

The code below is generating Published Artifacts in a drop folder but as a zip file. And this task works on only .Net core projects.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: 'src/myproj/*.csproj'
    arguments: -o $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)
```

If we add `zipAfterPublish: false` property to inputs, we can avoid zipping artifacts as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53271378/azure-pipelines-task-publishbuildartifacts-avoid-zip)

---

**Asp.Net - Publish Artifact Task**

The code below is the Asp.Net version of the above

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: '$(Parameters.ArtifactName)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

While we can avoid zipping artifacts in .Net Core, there isn't any property to add for this in Asp.Net version.

So, how can i avoid zipping artifacts in Asp.Net version of Publish Artifact task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the YAML Snippet of **PublishBuildArtifacts** task form  this  [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops#yaml-snippet) then, you will find that it don't have any input property like `zipAfterPublish`  of **DotNetCoreCLI** task to avoid the zip file while publishing artifact.

So, it's not possible to do it directly what you want to achieve. But there is a workaround which we can apply to achieve your desired result. That is by using the **ExtractFile** task.

Here I'm providing the detailed approach that you should use to get your desired result.

```yaml
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'PublishArtifact'
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifactName: '$(Parameters.ArtifactName)'   
    
# archive the build artifact for later processing
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false  

# Extract files
# just extract it as an extra step as I mentioned above
- task: ExtractFiles@1
  inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/$***.zip' 
    destinationFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/***'
    cleanDestinationFolder: false

# and lastly deploy it.
```

For more information check this [Extract Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/extract-files?view=azure-devops#yaml-snippet) documentation from Microsoft.